# Area formula for cyclic pentagon?

Tags: geometry

For a triangle, we have 
$$Area=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)},\qquad p=\frac{a+b+c}{2}.$$
For a cyclic quadrilateral, we have
$$Area=\sqrt{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)(p-d)},\qquad p=\frac{a+b+c+d}{2}.$$
Is there a similar formula for a cyclic pentagon?

Comment: There's a formula at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPentagon.html but it's not pretty. See also section 3.2.4 of Pavel Pech, Selected Topics in Geometry with Classical Vs. Computer Proving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The generalization of Heron formula to cyclic pentagon and hexagon can be found here:

[Areas of polygons inscribed in a circle](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02574377)

Also the more recent paper for general polygons:

[On the Areas of Cyclic and Semicyclic Polygons](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0407300v1.pdf)